# addEventListener don`t work

Tags: javascript, dom

why does not `addEventListener` work? The console is silent, there are no mistakes.

```js
function hide () {
  console.log(document.getElementById('text'));
  document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none';
  console.log(document.getElementById('text'));
}
console.log(document.getElementById('hider')); 
document.getElementById('hider').addEventListener('hide_element', hide);
```

```html
<input type="button" id="hider" value="Click to hide text" />

<div id="text">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add event listener to the `click` event, not `hide_element`

```js
function hide () {
  document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none';
}

document.getElementById('hider').addEventListener('click', hide);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="hider" value="Click to hide text" />

<div id="text">Text</div>
```

Comment: OMG, it`s work. But why the name of the addEventListener so important?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich It uses the name to detect for which event it will notify you

Comment: you can't make up your own event names (unless you also write some code to dispatch those event names)